# JDK 8 with Netbeans installer quits without warning

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, netbeans-8

When I try to install JDK 8 with Netbeans the installer quits immediately after configuring. I am using Windows 10 and attempting to install Java SE to JavaFX in my programming. The installer produces a log file when it quits, here is what the log file says:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005a996adf, pid=4088, tid=0x0000000000001f40
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001791f800):  JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8000, stack(0x000000001a4f0000,0x000000001a5f0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000001a5ef160, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x000000001ac3c890
RSP=0x000000001a5ef108, RBP=0x000000001a5ef310, RSI=0x0000000000000035, RDI=0x000000001791f9f8
R8 =0x000000001ac3c890, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x000000001a5ec7e0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000001a039460, R14=0x000000001a5ef350, R15=0x000000001791f800
RIP=0x000000005a996adf, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001a5ef108)
0x000000001a5ef108:   0000000059ee9ec6 0000000000000000
0x000000001a5ef118:   000000001791f9f8 0000000000000035
0x000000001a5ef128:   000000001ac3c890 000000001791f9f8
0x000000001a5ef138:   0000000059eea889 000000001ac3c890
0x000000001a5ef148:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001a5ef158:   000000005a27fdb3 0000000000000000
0x000000001a5ef168:   0000000000000000 000000001791f800
0x000000001a5ef178:   00000000ffffffff 00000000ffffffff
0x000000001a5ef188:   000000005a35c0c9 000000001791f800
0x000000001a5ef198:   0000000017812940 0000000000000000
0x000000001a5ef1a8:   000000000000056c 0000000000000000
0x000000001a5ef1b8:   0000000000000000 000000001791f800
0x000000001a5ef1c8:   000000005a2a89e8 000000001791f800
0x000000001a5ef1d8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001a5ef1e8:   00003a6e429acf95 0000000000000005
0x000000001a5ef1f8:   000000001791f800 0000000000000001 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000005a996adf)
0x000000005a996abf:   99 03 00 cc 33 c0 48 8b 5c 24 40 48 8b 74 24 48
0x000000005a996acf:   48 83 c4 30 5f c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 8b c1
0x000000005a996adf:   0f b7 10 48 83 c0 02 66 85 d2 75 f4 48 2b c1 48
0x000000005a996aef:   d1 f8 48 ff c8 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 45 33 c0 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000001a5ef160 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001791f800
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000001ac3c890 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001a5ef108 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001791f800
RBP=0x000000001a5ef310 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001791f800
RSI=0x0000000000000035 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000001791f9f8 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000001ac3c890 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000001a5ec7e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001791f800
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x000000001a039468} 'getDisplayNameOf' '(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;' in 'sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2'
R14=0x000000001a5ef350 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001791f800
R15=0x000000001791f800 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000001a4f0000,0x000000001a5f0000],  sp=0x000000001a5ef108,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getDisplayNameOf(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;+0
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$1600(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;+4
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/String;+15
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run()V+7
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x000000001791f800 JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8000, stack(0x000000001a4f0000,0x000000001a5f0000)]
  0x0000000017917000 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1416, stack(0x000000001a160000,0x000000001a260000)]
  0x0000000017895000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=1432, stack(0x000000001a060000,0x000000001a160000)]
  0x0000000017840800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6116, stack(0x0000000018600000,0x0000000018700000)]
  0x000000001783f800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=4656, stack(0x0000000018500000,0x0000000018600000)]
  0x000000001783f000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=844, stack(0x0000000018400000,0x0000000018500000)]
  0x0000000016d08800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8636, stack(0x00000000170e0000,0x00000000171e0000)]
  0x000000001536e800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=860, stack(0x0000000016be0000,0x0000000016ce0000)]
  0x000000001536b800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4332, stack(0x0000000016ae0000,0x0000000016be0000)]
  0x000000001537a000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9228, stack(0x00000000169e0000,0x0000000016ae0000)]
  0x0000000015377800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10284, stack(0x00000000168e0000,0x00000000169e0000)]
  0x0000000015376000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4888, stack(0x00000000167e0000,0x00000000168e0000)]
  0x000000001535a800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10276, stack(0x00000000165e0000,0x00000000166e0000)]
  0x00000000048f0800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=932, stack(0x00000000164e0000,0x00000000165e0000)]
  0x0000000002f4d800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=9284, stack(0x0000000004700000,0x0000000004800000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000015338800 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000163e0000,0x00000000164e0000] [id=2884]
  0x0000000016d3c000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000171e0000,0x00000000172e0000] [id=8048]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 24975K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 38% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fc363fb0,0x00000000feb00000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ff580000,0x00000000ff580000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000feb00000,0x00000000feb00000,0x00000000ff580000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000fab00000)
 Metaspace       used 16665K, capacity 16876K, committed 17408K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 2103K, capacity 2195K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000013cc0000,0x0000000013d50000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000013540000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005a8da6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000014150000, 0x0000000014550000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014550000, 0x0000000014950000)

Polling page: 0x0000000002ea0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=3200Kb max_used=3200Kb free=242559Kb
 bounds [0x0000000004900000, 0x0000000004c30000, 0x0000000013900000]
 total_blobs=1451 nmethods=938 adapters=426
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 2.780 Thread 0x000000001536e800  934   !   3       javax.swing.JComponent::getClientProperty (56 bytes)
Event: 2.780 Thread 0x000000001536e800 nmethod 934 0x0000000004c1ee50 code [0x0000000004c1efe0, 0x0000000004c1f408]
Event: 2.798 Thread 0x000000001536e800  935       1       java.util.EventObject::getSource (5 bytes)
Event: 2.799 Thread 0x000000001536e800 nmethod 935 0x0000000004c1f550 code [0x0000000004c1f6a0, 0x0000000004c1f7b0]
Event: 2.812 Thread 0x000000001536e800  936       3       java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject::doSignal (43 bytes)
Event: 2.812 Thread 0x000000001536e800 nmethod 936 0x0000000004c1f810 code [0x0000000004c1f980, 0x0000000004c1fd08]
Event: 2.845 Thread 0x000000001536e800  937       3       java.awt.Component::getFont (5 bytes)
Event: 2.846 Thread 0x000000001536e800 nmethod 937 0x0000000004c1fe10 code [0x0000000004c1ffa0, 0x0000000004c204a8]
Event: 2.846 Thread 0x000000001536e800  938       3       java.awt.Component::getFont_NoClientCode (29 bytes)
Event: 2.847 Thread 0x000000001536e800 nmethod 938 0x0000000004c20610 code [0x0000000004c207a0, 0x0000000004c20bc8]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 1.477 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000004b0f160 method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 62
Event: 1.478 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000004b0f160 method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 62
Event: 1.547 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000004b1acbc method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 271
Event: 1.548 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000004ad2ca8 method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 62
Event: 1.855 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000004a9f510 method=java.lang.String.startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z @ 25
Event: 2.362 Thread 0x0000000017895000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000004abe028 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 2.362 Thread 0x0000000017895000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000004abe028 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 2.362 Thread 0x0000000017895000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000004abe028 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 2.362 Thread 0x0000000017895000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000004abe028 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 2.758 Thread 0x0000000017895000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000004bf53b4 method=java.util.Hashtable.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 48

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.248 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000fab7e128) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.248 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000fab7e338) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.319 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000fabec0e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.319 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000fabec4d8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.320 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000fabefd28) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.320 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000fabf0120) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 1.619 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000fbae8df0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 1.705 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000fbbb4848) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 1.708 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000fbbc1f38) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 1.836 Thread 0x0000000002f4d800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000fbcaa638) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]

Events (10 events):
Event: 2.428 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$5 done
Event: 2.670 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$18
Event: 2.670 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$18 done
Event: 2.670 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$ColumnComparator$1
Event: 2.671 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$ColumnComparator$1 done
Event: 2.673 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$11
Event: 2.673 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$11 done
Event: 2.758 Thread 0x0000000017895000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x0000000004bf53b4
Event: 2.758 Thread 0x0000000017895000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000004bf53b4 sp=0x000000001a15d5d0
Event: 2.758 Thread 0x0000000017895000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000494582a sp=0x000000001a15d588 mode 2


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff736b80000 - 0x00007ff736bb7000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffcd4890000 - 0x00007ffcd4a70000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffcd3b60000 - 0x00007ffcd3c0e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffcd0cb0000 - 0x00007ffcd0f16000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffcd2340000 - 0x00007ffcd23e1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffcd4440000 - 0x00007ffcd44dd000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffcd47f0000 - 0x00007ffcd484b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffcd4540000 - 0x00007ffcd465f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffcd4660000 - 0x00007ffcd47ef000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffcd0c90000 - 0x00007ffcd0cb0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffcd26f0000 - 0x00007ffcd2718000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffcd1b60000 - 0x00007ffcd1cf3000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffcd1ac0000 - 0x00007ffcd1b5b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffcd19c0000 - 0x00007ffcd1ab6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffcc3100000 - 0x00007ffcc3369000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.16299.248_none_15ced204935f55d7\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffcd1e60000 - 0x00007ffcd2168000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffcd1890000 - 0x00007ffcd1902000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffcd2550000 - 0x00007ffcd257d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x000000005a960000 - 0x000000005aa32000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000005a0c0000 - 0x000000005a95a000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffcd2330000 - 0x00007ffcd2338000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffcb7bb0000 - 0x00007ffcb7bb9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffccee50000 - 0x00007ffccee73000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffcca290000 - 0x00007ffcca29a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffcd2190000 - 0x00007ffcd21fc000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffccedf0000 - 0x00007ffccee1a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\winmmbase.dll
0x00007ffcd10f0000 - 0x00007ffcd113a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x000000005a0b0000 - 0x000000005a0bf000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\verify.dll
0x000000005a080000 - 0x000000005a0a9000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\java.dll
0x000000005a060000 - 0x000000005a076000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffcd2720000 - 0x00007ffcd3b56000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffcd2280000 - 0x00007ffcd2326000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ffcd1140000 - 0x00007ffcd1887000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffcd42d0000 - 0x00007ffcd4321000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffcd0c00000 - 0x00007ffcd0c11000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffcd0c20000 - 0x00007ffcd0c6c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ffcd0be0000 - 0x00007ffcd0bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffcd0640000 - 0x00007ffcd0657000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x00007ffcd0070000 - 0x00007ffcd00a3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00007ffcd0740000 - 0x00007ffcd0765000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ffcd0ae0000 - 0x00007ffcd0b09000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffcd0630000 - 0x00007ffcd063b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000000005a040000 - 0x000000005a05a000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffcd0470000 - 0x00007ffcd04d6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ffcd0200000 - 0x00007ffcd0239000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ffcd4850000 - 0x00007ffcd4858000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffcca510000 - 0x00007ffcca526000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00007ffcca4f0000 - 0x00007ffcca50a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000000005a020000 - 0x000000005a031000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000017e20000 - 0x0000000017e27000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\nbi-4948696883151101294.tmp
0x00007ffcd2400000 - 0x00007ffcd2549000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
0x0000000059e80000 - 0x000000005a018000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\awt.dll
0x00007ffcd3c10000 - 0x00007ffcd3cd5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ffccf060000 - 0x00007ffccf0e8000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ffccf1e0000 - 0x00007ffccf275000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ffcd2580000 - 0x00007ffcd26e7000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffcb1ee0000 - 0x00007ffcb1f89000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll
0x00007ffccf450000 - 0x00007ffccf47a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x0000000059e30000 - 0x0000000059e77000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x00007ffca46c0000 - 0x00007ffca4766000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.16299.248_none_8879e63c4abacc42\comctl32.dll
0x00007ffcb80c0000 - 0x00007ffcb80d9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CLDAPI.dll
0x00007ffcb8070000 - 0x00007ffcb80b4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AEPIC.dll
0x00007ffcc80d0000 - 0x00007ffcc80da000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\FLTLIB.DLL
0x00007ffccfd20000 - 0x00007ffccfd51000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
0x00007ffcd1d60000 - 0x00007ffcd1dfe000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
0x00007ffccd9c0000 - 0x00007ffccdb71000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\propsys.dll
0x00007ffca2f00000 - 0x00007ffca3027000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll
0x00007ffccc220000 - 0x00007ffccc814000     C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreUAPCommonProxyStub.dll
0x00007ffccd110000 - 0x00007ffccd2bb000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x00007ffcb4ac0000 - 0x00007ffcb4b1b000     C:\Windows\System32\thumbcache.dll
0x0000000059de0000 - 0x0000000059e22000     C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\NBI79156.tmp\_jvm\bin\t2k.dll
0x00007ffcc9f20000 - 0x00007ffcc9f3b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ffcc2750000 - 0x00007ffcc275b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\drprov.dll
0x00007ffccfd90000 - 0x00007ffccfde5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINSTA.dll
0x00007ffcb7fa0000 - 0x00007ffcb7fb6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntlanman.dll
0x00007ffcb7f80000 - 0x00007ffcb7f9c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\davclnt.dll
0x00007ffcb81d0000 - 0x00007ffcb81dc000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DAVHLPR.dll
0x00007ffccc820000 - 0x00007ffccc837000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wkscli.dll
0x00007ffcb4b40000 - 0x00007ffcb4b52000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cscapi.dll
0x00007ffcd0300000 - 0x00007ffcd030e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\netutils.dll
0x00007ffca4bd0000 - 0x00007ffca4c1a000     C:\Windows\System32\dlnashext.dll
0x00007ffca3030000 - 0x00007ffca3093000     C:\Windows\System32\PlayToDevice.dll
0x00007ffca64c0000 - 0x00007ffca64df000     C:\Windows\System32\DevDispItemProvider.dll
0x00007ffcc5ca0000 - 0x00007ffcc5d0f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x00007ffcd09f0000 - 0x00007ffcd0a17000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00007ffca32a0000 - 0x00007ffca347f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wpdshext.dll
0x00007ffcc2f60000 - 0x00007ffcc30fc000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.16299.248_none_46b9c4e9edf1cfa5\gdiplus.dll
0x00007ffcca1b0000 - 0x00007ffcca250000     C:\Windows\System32\PortableDeviceApi.dll
0x00007ffcd3e80000 - 0x00007ffcd42ce000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x00007ffcd1d00000 - 0x00007ffcd1d58000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINTRUST.dll
0x00007ffcd0c70000 - 0x00007ffcd0c82000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll
0x00007ffcd0f20000 - 0x00007ffcd10ee000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00007ffcb4830000 - 0x00007ffcb4866000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorShell.dll
0x00007ffca2cf0000 - 0x00007ffca2d15000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorAPI.dll
0x00007ffccd9a0000 - 0x00007ffccd9b3000     C:\Windows\System32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007ffcb4960000 - 0x00007ffcb4970000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LINKINFO.dll
0x00007ffcc6e60000 - 0x00007ffcc6e6c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
0x00007ffcd0b10000 - 0x00007ffcd0b40000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL
0x00007ffcafbd0000 - 0x00007ffcafbd9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IconCodecService.dll
0x00007ffcc7d90000 - 0x00007ffcc7f58000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\ -Xmx256m -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans -Dnetbeans.default_cachedir_root=C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache 
java_command: org.netbeans.installer.Installer
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Temp\\NBI79156.tmp\bundle.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\mattl\Desktop\Projects\path_items\MinerGate-cli-4.04-win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Users\mattl\Anaconda3;C:\Users\mattl\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\mattl\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\mattl\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\mattl\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\PothosSDR\bin;C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin
USERNAME=mattl
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
```

I would just like to apologize, I am new to StackOverflow and it will not allow me to submit this post without adding more words since there is too much code. It's unfortunate that it does not consider issues such as the one I'm facing, where it's not necessarily code just a long error message. This text is unimportant it is just to increase the character count.

Comment: This JRE is quite old. I prefer to install the very latest JDK (or at least the latest 1.8 build (currently 1.8u162), if you want to stick with 1.8 for now) from the standalone JDK installer first. And then install Netbeans (just Netbeans, not Netbeans with jdk). That way, you have two independent installations which you can independently update.

Comment: I've tried what was said about, but the issue was that Netbeans would not open a new project. When I clicked the new project button, it wouldn't do anything. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug inside JRE. You can do nothing about this, just send a bug report to the link provided:

```
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Try to use 32-bit version instead of 64. Try to use another JRE version

Comment: I still get the same error with a 32-bit version. Can you link me to another JRE version?